# Angular >2 Subject subscribe directly or use a method?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a service with a Subject member. The Subject provides an instance of a class:

```
public selectedProjectSubject: Subject<Project> = new Subject();
```

The value of the Subject is updated with a method:

```
public updateSelectedProject(project: Project) {
    this.selectedProjectSubject.next(project);
  }
```

In several classes i subscribe on the Subject:

```
this.projectSubscription = this.projectService.selectedProjectSubject.subscribe((project: Project) => {
      this.projectSelected = project;
    });
```

Is it a good practice to subscribe directly on the Subject or provide the Subject (Observable) with another method?

Comment: If you want your Project object to be shared across different places of your app and have it updated everywhere when you pass a new Project to your Subject, then it's the way to go. You shouldn't return the Subject itself using a method, just subscribe to it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're very welcome. RxJS and Observables tend to follow a functional programming paradigm, hence the reason why you should try to avoid setters and getters :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use `BehaviorSubject` in a number of places and I want to discourage my teammates from using `.value` outside of the service containing the subject so I usually do the following for all subjects:

```
private _selectedProject = new Subject<Project>();
get selectedProject(): Observable<Project> {
  return this._selectedProject;
}
```

However, there really isn't much concern with accessing it the way you have it and you can always change to my approach later if you have need of it without even refactoring any of the callers by just using a `get` accessor.

Comment: This is my confusion. A (Behaviour)Subject is an Observable to subscribe to it. However my OO background says that this class member should be encapsulated and exposed with a getter and setter. But i can imagine that this approach is different in JavaScript RxJs.

Comment: OO teaches encapsulation, not getters and setters.  A class should have a public API and a private API.  Java promotes getters and setters because it allows for future refactoring not because it gives you encapsulation.  A field that has the standard getter/setter is not encapsulated.


Should your selected project be encapsulated?  That depends on the purpose of the service.  Services store the current state of your app and encapsulate the business logic of your app.  Components are responsible for the display and I/O manipulation.

Comment: For example.  Maybe you want part of the page to display the currently selected project name.  If you want to encapsulate the project then you should create an observable that exposes the name called `selectedProjectName` or something like that.  Whether or not you should encapsulate the currently selected project is more nuanced.  If the selected project had 10 fields and you wanted to display all of them it would be silly to encapsulate the selected project object and create getters for all of the fields.

Comment: My personal preference would be to have a CurrentProjectService which controls the currently selected project and exposes it as an observable.  The public API of the service would be `setSelectedProject(project: Project)`, `get selectedProject(): Observable<Project>` and possibly `clearSelectedProject(): void`.

Comment: Thanks for your time and explanation. However i disagree with your point of view regarding encapsulation: 
Encapsulation in Java is a mechanism of wrapping the data (variables) and code acting on the data (methods) together as a single unit. In encapsulation, the variables of a class will be hidden from other classes, and can be accessed only through the methods of their current class. Therefore, it is also known as data hiding.